# how to change duplicates in a column by applying a function to rows by a condition in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame:

```
    df = read.table(text="mi    chr pos EF1 EF2 EF3
    m1  A   2352026 TT  CC  CC
    m2  A   2352026 AA  CC  CC
    m3  A   2352026 GG  GG  GG
    m4  B   44049171    TT  TT  TT
    m5  B   44049171    AA  AA  AA
    m6  C   6769989 CC  CC  CC
    m7  C   6769989 TT  GG  GG
    m8  D   44814175    TT  TT  TT
    m9  D   44814175    GG  GG  GG
    m10 D   44814175    TT  TT  TT
    m11 D   44814175    TT  TT  TT
    m12 D   45931126    CC  CC  CC", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

I would like to change duplicated values (if the same in Column 2) in column3 to make unique, by adding 1. So my expected result is:

```
    mi  chr pos EF1 EF2 EF3
    m1  A   2352026 TT  CC  CC
    m2  A   2352027 AA  CC  CC
    m3  A   2352028 GG  GG  GG
    m4  B   44049171    TT  TT  TT
    m5  B   44049172    AA  AA  AA
    m6  C   6769989 CC  CC  CC
    m7  C   6769990 TT  GG  GG
    m8  D   44814175    TT  TT  TT
    m9  D   44814176    GG  GG  GG
    m10 D   44814177    TT  TT  TT
    m11 D   44814178    TT  TT  TT
    m12 D   45931126    CC  CC  CC
```

I know how to subset the duplicated rows:

```
   df[duplicated(df[,c("chr","pos")]),]
```

and a function to change all duplicates:

```
     change = function(x) {
      success <- FALSE
      while (!success) {
        # change the duplicated positions for each group (column2)
        x$pos[duplicated(x[,c("chr","pos")])] <- x$pos[duplicated(x[,c("chr","pos")])] + 1
        # check for still having duplicates positions
        success <- sum(duplicated(x[,c("chr","pos")])) > 0
      }
    return(x)
    }
```

When I run

```
change(df)
```

The result I got is not what I expected. I don't know how to fix this issue. Thanks for any helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df$pos + ave(df$pos, df$pos, FUN = seq_along) - 1
# [1]  2352026  2352027  2352028 44049171 44049172  6769989  6769990 44814175
# [9] 44814176 44814177 44814178 45931126
```

Comment: your answer is much simple than what I thought. Thanks.